# C# Regex Replacing

Tags: c#, regex, replace

So basically, I have a string like this:

```
    Some Text Here | More Text Here | Even More Text Here
```

And I want to be able to replace the text between the two bars with `New Text`, so it would end up like:

```
    Some Text Here | New Text | Even More Text Here
```

I'm assuming the best way is with regexes... so I tried a bunch of things but couldn't get anything to work... Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple case like this, the best apprach is a simple string split:

```
string input = "foo|bar|baz";
string[] things = input.Split('|');
things[1] = "roflcopter";
string output = string.Join("|", things); // output contains "foo|roflcopter|baz";
```

This relies on a few things:

- There are always 3 pipe-delimited text strings.
- There is no insignificant spaces between the pipes.

To correct the second, do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < things.Length; ++i)
    things[i] = things[i].Trim();
```

To remove whitespace from the beginning and end of each element.

The general rule with regexes is that they should usually be your last resort; not your first. :)

Comment: +1 for pragmatic approach.  I like regex as much as the next guy, but if a simpler approach works I'm all for it.

Comment: Indeed. It's also very easy to write seemingly innocuous regexes that perform appallingly (often in cases where it cannot find a match). If I can get what I want with basic string methods like `Split`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` or `Contains` then I usually will.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regex...try this:

```
String testString = "Some Text Here | More Text Here | Even More Text Here";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(testString,
                        @"(.*)\|([^|]+)\|(.*)",
                        "$1| New Text |$3",
                         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```